# How to make a Weibull fit on an existing histogram?

Tags: scipy, statistics, weibull

I created a histogram plot based on my datasets. I would like to create a Weibull fit for this histogram.
I used scipy and the stats.weibull function, but unfortunately, it does not work.

Do you have an idea of how to use the stats.weibull in this case?

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats

data = 'Figures/Histogram/Histogram.xlsx'
hist= pd.read_excel('Histogram/Histogram.xlsx')

# x= hist['DeltaT_value'] 
x= hist['DeltaT_-250_2017']
X=x[(x>0)]

plt.figure(figsize=(15,4))
plt.hist(X, bins= np.arange (0,1500,25), color='#0504aa', edgecolor ='red', rwidth= 0.8)
plt.ylabel('Number of EL')
plt.xlabel('Delta T (years CE) between EL')
plt.xlim(0, 401)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,401,25))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,2.2,1))`


# Weibull 
####

shape, loc, scale = stats.weibull_min.fit(X)
x = np.linspace(stats.weibull_min.ppf(0.01, shape, loc=loc, scale=scale), stats.weibull_min.ppf(0.99, shape, loc=loc, scale=scale), 100)
plt.plot(x, stats.weibull_min.pdf(x, shape, loc=loc, scale=scale), 'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='weibull')
```

I tried this:

```
shape, loc, scale = stats.weibull_min.fit(X)
x = np.linspace(stats.weibull_min.ppf(0.01, shape, loc=loc, scale=scale), stats.weibull_min.ppf(0.99, shape, loc=loc, scale=scale), 100)
plt.plot(x, stats.weibull_min.pdf(x, shape, loc=loc, scale=scale), 'r-', lw=5, alpha=0.6, label='weibull')
```

Unfortunately, it seems another graph is created on top of the histogram instead of a fit.

Comment: Interesting, but it's a little unclear. I don't understand what you mean "another graph is created on top of the histogram instead of a fit". Couple of ideas anyway. (1) If you still have the original data from which the histogram was constructed, use those same data to fit a Weibull distribution -- that's the best result in any event, since the histogram is just an approximation to start with. (2) If the original data aren't available, you can generate an approximate data sample by replicating the centers of the histogram bars a number of times (proportional to each bin mass) and fit that.

Comment: Idea (2) is an approximation to the right thing to do, which is to treat the histogram as censored data (you know a range that the data fall into, instead of a specific value). Working with censored data isn't hard, but you might need to implement it yourself; you can decide whether you want to go down that road. Further discussion should go to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for the reply and 2 ideas.

The histogram is not an approximation but rather a distribution of my data.
The only thing I need to try is to see if there is a statistical fit for this histogram.
In seismology, a specific distribution (Gamma or Weibull) is associated with either one type of earthquake or another. I need to see in which category the data fall.

Comment: Hi Mat, thanks for your reply. I understand your problem of assessing goodness of fit for two candidate distributions, that makes a lot of sense. The most straightforward thing to do is to find the best-fitting parameters for each distribution from the log likelihood function as computed from the original data, compute the log likelihood for those parameters, and see which is greater. (A Bayesian approach would modify that, but probably the results would come out not too different.) It is straightforward to construct a log likelihood for a histogram, by treating it as censored data,

Comment: but you would only do that if you don't have the original data at hand. Consider this -- the results that you get from a histogram are going to vary with the bin size, number of bins, whether bins are all the same size or different sizes. But that's irrelevant to the goal of figuring out the earthquake distribution, right? If you work with the original data, that stuff doesn't come into play (as it shouldn't).

Comment: Very interesting comment! 
This is true, depending on the number of bins and bin size, the "shape" and distribution changes, it seems to be a bias.
Any advice on how to use a log likelihood function (I have never used it before). Many thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 0):

After working on it for a little while, I found a solution:

```
shape, loc, scale = stats.weibull_min.fit(X, floc = 0, f0 = 1)
W = np.linspace(stats.weibull_min.ppf(0.001, shape, loc=loc, scale=scale), stats.weibull_min.ppf(0.99, shape, loc=loc, scale=scale), 1000)

p =  stats.weibull_min.pdf(W, shape, scale = scale)
```

Robert Dodier's comments on my original post are very interesting and I will try to see how I can use a "log likelihood function" on the original dataset rather than a fit on the histogram. This is the first time I will use a log likelihood function. If anyone has some advice, I would gladly take it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mat, here's what I get with the approach I was arguing for, which is to work with the likelihood function as derived from quantile data (i.e., the cumulative summation of histogram bars).

I've devised some code for the computer algebra system Maxima (https://maxima.sourceforge.io) to do the calculations. I'll link to the code, but it's probably difficult to use at this point; mostly what I want to say is that this business about working with the likelihood function is a good path forward. See also my comments on this other question about deriving the likelihood function for binned data: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11176/can-anyone-explain-quantile-maximum-probability-estimation-qmpe/442966#442966

The code I'm using is the package `robert-dodier/qmpe` under https://github.com/maxima-project-on-github/maxima-packages . That in turn makes use of as-yet-unreleased functions (to be released in the next version of Maxima, namely 5.47) from the Maxima package `distrib`; that unreleased version may be found at https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/share/distrib/ .

Looks like the data shown in the histograms is just:

```
q: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325];
n: [0,  1,  3,  2,   2,   3,   0,   2,   1,   0,   1,   1,   0,   1];
```

with `q` being the quantiles (0, 25, 50, ... 325 years) and `n` being the number of events in each bin (0, 1, 2, or 3 being the only observed values).

I tried a lognormal distribution and a Weibull distribution. Other distributions are possible by the same method, I just haven't written the code for them yet; I might still try it.

For the lognormal, I get `mu = 4.546, sigma = 0.7794`, with negative log likelihood `nll = 2.528`. For the Weibull, I get `shape = 1.488, scale = 136.2`, with `nll = 2.491`. Here are figures comparing lognormal to data and Weibull to data. The green line is the final fit; the red line, barely visible in the Weibull plot, is from the initial parameters for the optimization.

[image: lognormal pdf compared to data]

[image: Weibull pdf compared to data]

As you can see, the Weibull fit is a little better as determined from nll, but neither one is really very good, and in fact it's likely there's no distribution that gives a good fit -- there are only a few data per bin and they're pretty noisy.

As a postscript, here is the code I am working with to generate the figures shown. As I was saying, I don't expect anyone to run this code, it's just to present the general method about working with the likelihood function as derive from the histogram data.

```
/* inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75090377/how-to-make-a-weibull-fit-on-an-existing-histogram */

/* data shown in histogram https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYt70.png
 * values appear to be just 0, 1, 2, or 3
 */

q: [0, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325];
n: [0,  1,  3,  2,   2,   3,   0,   2,   1,   0,   1,   1,   0,   1];
p_unnormalized: makelist (lsum (n1, n1, firstn (n, k)), k, 1, length (n));
p: p_unnormalized / last (p_unnormalized);

load (distrib);

load ("qmpe.mac");

quux: construct_qmpe (cdf_weibull (u, shape, scale), 'u, '[shape, scale], mle_weibull, 1e-4, [1, 0]);

mumble: quux (q, p);

set_plot_option ([svg_file, "./SO-75090377-weibull-fit-compare-cdf.svg"]);
plot_qmpe_comparison_cdf (q, p, cdf_weibull (u, shape, scale), u, '[shape, scale], quantile_weibull (0.99, shape, scale), assoc ('initial, mumble), assoc ('final, mumble));

set_plot_option ([svg_file, "./SO-75090377-weibull-fit-compare-pdf.svg"]);
plot_qmpe_comparison_pdf (q, p, pdf_weibull (u, shape, scale), u, '[shape, scale], quantile_weibull (0.99, shape, scale), assoc ('initial, mumble), assoc ('final, mumble));

foo: construct_qmpe (cdf_lognormal (u, location, scale), 'u, '[location, scale], mle_lognormal, 1e-4, [1, 0]);

baz: foo (q, p);

set_plot_option ([svg_file, "./SO-75090377-lognormal-fit-compare-cdf.svg"]);
plot_qmpe_comparison_cdf (q, p, cdf_lognormal (u, location, scale), u, '[location, scale], quantile_lognormal (0.99, location, scale), assoc ('initial, baz), assoc ('final, baz));

set_plot_option ([svg_file, "./SO-75090377-lognormal-fit-compare-pdf.svg"]);
plot_qmpe_comparison_pdf (q, p, pdf_lognormal (u, location, scale), u, '[location, scale], quantile_lognormal (0.99, location, scale), assoc ('initial, baz), assoc ('final, baz));

ev (assoc ('nll, mumble), assoc ('final, mumble), nouns, numer);
ev (assoc ('nll, baz), assoc ('final, baz), nouns, numer);
```